# StateFlow And LazyColumn recomposition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I have a question related to `StateFlow` and UI recomposition. In short, my ViewModel has three flows:

`accountFlow`, which is used to fetch the currently logged-in account from the database.

`timelinePositionFlow`, which is used to retrieve the last browsing position record from the currently logged-in account.

`timelineFlow`, which contains all posts stored in the database for the currently logged-in account.

The issue I'm facing is that my app can switch between multiple accounts and browse information. Since each account has a stored timeline position, I need to use `rememberLazyListState(initialFirstVisibleItemIndex = ...)` to initialize the position of the LazyColumn. However, if I switch accounts and StateFlow emits the value of the new account, the `rememberLazyListState` won't recomposition. so that the size of the timeline of the new account may only be 20, and the timeline Position Index of the old account is greater than 20, which will cause a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` error
Is there a good way to solve this problem?

viewModel

```kotlin
  private val activeAccountFlow = accountDao
    .getActiveAccountFlow()
    .filterNotNull()
    .distinctUntilChanged { old, new -> old.id == new.id }

  val timelinePosition = activeAccountFlow
    .mapLatest { TimelinePosition(it.firstVisibleItemIndex, it.offset) }
    .stateIn(
      scope = viewModelScope,
      started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
      initialValue = TimelinePosition()
    )

  val timeline = activeAccountFlow
    .flatMapLatest { timelineDao.getStatusListWithFlow(it.id) }
    .map { splitReorderStatus(it).toUiData().toImmutableList() }
    .stateIn(
      scope = viewModelScope,
      started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
      initialValue = persistentListOf()
    )
```

UI

```kotlin
  val timeline by viewModel.timeline.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
  val timelinePosition by viewModel.timelinePosition.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

  val lazyState = rememberLazyListState(
    initialFirstVisibleItemIndex = timelinePosition.index,
    initialFirstVisibleItemScrollOffset = timelinePosition.offset
  )

  LazyColumn { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving `LazyListState` manually. By setting the first argument of `rememberSaveable` to `timelinePosition`, `lazyState` will reset when `timelinePosition` changes.

```
    val lazyState = rememberSaveable(timelinePosition, saver = LazyListState.Saver) {
        LazyListState(timelinePosition.index, timelinePosition.offset)
    }
```

**Edit:**
If `timelinePosition` is updated on `lazyState` change, then this approach won't work, because it will introduce a cyclic dependency. In this case i would recommend to change the way you are getting `timelinePosition`. You don't really need a `StateFlow`, as you only need to read it once when the active user changes. Add a one-shot suspend method to the `accountDao` and `ViewModel` to get `timelinePosition` and use it when `timeline` changes, something like:

```
    LaunchedEffect(timeline) {
        timelinePosition = viewModel.getTimeLinePosition(activeUserId)
        lazyState.animateScrollToItem(timelinePosition.index, timelinePosition.offset)
    }
```

Comment: I have tried using this method. If I use remember/rememberSaveable (timelinePosition), its lazyState.firstVisibleItemIndex will not update and will always remain the initial value. However, I have some functionalities that rely on LaunchedEffect(firstVisibleItemIndex) to complete, such as saving timeline position

Comment: @Afterglow can you add `LaunchedEffect(firstVisibleItemIndex)` where you update timeline position? Also, I think there is no need to receive timeline position as a `StateFlow`, see the answer edit.

Comment: I think this method is good. I am trying to use this method to implement functions, but I currently encounter some data out-of-synchronization problems. For example, the active account has changed, but the timeline will still be the previous account for a short period of time, which will cause `lazyState.scrollTo` is not executed correctly, I'm still working on how to avoid this

Comment: @Afterglow Maybe [combine](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/state-production#stream-apis) all the flows you need so they will be updated together

Comment: @Janltor I tried to combine the account flow and timeline flow, but my timeline flow requires an active account id to retrieve. I don't know what to do now :(

Comment: @Janltor I solved this problem ! I will post my answer

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of hard exploration, I solved the problem!!! :)

A properly working flow looks like this:

```
private val activeAccountFlow = accountDao
  .getActiveAccountFlow()
  .distinctUntilChanged { old, new -> old?.id == new?.id }
  .filterNotNull()

val homeCombinedFlow = activeAccountFlow
  .flatMapLatest { account ->
    val timelineFlow = timelineDao.getStatusListWithFlow(account.id)
    timelineFlow.map {
      HomeUserData(
        activeAccount = account,
        timeline = splitReorderStatus(it).toUiData().toImmutableList(),
        position = TimelinePosition(account.firstVisibleItemIndex, account.offset)
      )
    }
  }
  .stateIn(
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.Eagerly,
    initialValue = null
  )
```

Next is the UI part, since only need to recomposition the LazyColumn when the activeAccount is changed, the remember key should be set to activeAccount.id

```
  val lazyState = rememberSaveable(activeAccount.id, saver = LazyListState.Saver) {
    LazyListState(timelinePosition.index, timelinePosition.offset)
  }
  val firstVisibleIndex by remember(lazyState) {
    derivedStateOf {
      lazyState.firstVisibleItemIndex
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you please explain what's causing issue. It will be easier to understand solution once you explain what's causing issue in your previous solution.

Comment: @DarshanMistry I think it's the flatMapLatest method that causes the flow to get out of sync